# What does \( mean in a bash script

Tags: bash, escaping, parentheses

I am editing someone else's `.sh`, and I came across this line

```
if [ "$ACTION" = "install" -o \( "$ACTION" = "start" -a -z "$APPS" \) ]
```

What I understand:

- `"$ACTION" = "install"` is checking if the script's action is to install
- `-o` is the OR operator
- `"$ACTION" = "start"` is checking if the script is starting another program
- `-a` is the AND operator
- `-z "$APPS"` is checking if $APPS is an empty string

I don't know what `\( "$ACTION" = "start" -a -z "$APPS" \)` means. Is the backslash parenthesis ( `\( <action> \)` ) a start/end comment? I looked [here](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html) and this is not the normal conditional grouping that I would expect.

EDIT: To help represent what I thought was going on, this is the equivalent in most other programing languages. Because I am fairly new to bash, the open ended `||` didn't seem weird to me.

```java
if (ACTION == 'install' || /* ACTION == 'start' && APPS == '' */)
```

Comment: It's grouping the expressions, just like when writing math expressions in other programming languages.

Comment: In this case it is to group the inner expressions by escaping the `(` and `)`  characters, which can mean something else without the escape sequence.

Comment: @Barmar But how does that explain the backslash?

Comment: The backslash is the escape character to prevent it from being treated as starting a subshell. You could also write `'('`

Comment: `[` uses `(` for grouping. The shell uses `(` to start a subshell. `\(` escapes the `(` from the shell so that `[` can see it and so the shell doesn't throw an error: `[ \( x \) ] && echo ok; [ ( x ) ] && echo oops`

Comment: was the code like this as a matter of preference vs doing something like `if [ "$ACTION" = "install"] ||  [ "$ACTION" = "start" -a -z "$APPS" ]`? or does it have to be structured this way because of the `-a` and `-z` flags?

Comment: But the purpose of `\( \)` has been answered if someone wants to write an official answer for it.

Comment: BTW, re: your edit, it helps a lot to think of `[` as just another command, not a part of bash or `if` syntax. (And this is true: it _is_ just another command; bash has a built-in version of `test`, but that's just a performance enhancement; it generally behaves the same way `/usr/bin/[` would). That's why `-a` and `-o` were needed in the first place instead of `&&` and `||`: because the latter are shell syntax (and particularly, command separators), if used they would split the left half to be run by `[` and the right half to be evaluated as a separate command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\(` escapes the character `(` so it isn't treated as syntax by the shell and is instead passed as an argument to `test` (aka `[`). You could achieve the same effect with `'('` or `"("` as well.

Note that use of parenthesis for grouping (and all other cases where more than one test operation is performed per `test` invocation -- meaning `-a` and `-o` as well) is marked obsolescent in [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), and should not be used in new code (see the `OB` markers in the standards document).

A better way to write this would be:

```
if [ "$ACTION" = "install" ] || { [ "$ACTION" = "start" ] && [ -z "$APPS" ]; }; then
```

...or, using `[[` (a ksh and bash extension that provides parser support, making quotes unnecessary in most positions and allowing `(` and `)` to be parsed as part of the test operation without escaping needed):

```
if [[ $ACTION = install || ( $ACTION = start && -z $APPS ) ]]; then
```